# Facebook graph api post status

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post on my own feed , but im not able to ,as this page says we cant on feed directly but by using 'share' [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#publishing) 
can someone please explain? how to post on feed using simple curl command?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

It is no longer possible to post to a user profile with the API (or with `curl`), the docs are very clear about that. You can only use the Share Dialog.